# Constant URL Parameter in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, url-parameters, affiliate

Is there a way to keep variable url parameters with wordpress? Here is what I want to do:

My website is visited with the following parameter:
(mypage.de/?pid=31&prid=94)

As soon as the visitor clicks on a button or a subpage, the URL parameter disappears. Now I'm looking for a way to keep the parameter when clicking on a button or subpage.

Comment: What does the button do?    What is the code that powers the button, both client side and server side?

Comment: By clicking on a subsite, menu item, button etc.. the URL parameter should be retained. (I'm using Elementor/Wordpress)

Comment: What is the purpose of the parameter?   Why do you need it retained on other pages?   Have you considered storing that information in a cookie instead?

Comment: The parameter serves as an affiliate assignment. The use of cookies is not possible because it has caused problems for people with a cookie blocker in the past.